# Styling <hr> not displaying as expected

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/kWJ79/17/

1. Why is my `<hr>` so short?
2. Why is the gap at the bottom of the `#wrapper` bigger than the 20px padding size specified?

Comment: `<hr />` = Horizontal rule, not vertical rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. the parent `<div id="vr">` to your `<hr>` is set to width 1px (and float:left) so the `<hr>` is 1px wide
2. the `#wrapper` has extra space because of the `#wrapper:after` pseudo class adding a `display:block` and `content:"."` to the end of the wrapper gives it an extra line at the bottom, it's not extra padding

maybe consider `#wrapper {overflow:hidden;}` as an alternative to using an `:after` pseudo class

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/kWJ79/24/

Comment: Sorry I mean short horizontally, I'd like its bottom to be in line with the bottom of the #wrapper minus padding.

Comment: I've set `html, body, #wrapper` to `{height:100%}` which allows `#vr` to fill the height of `#wrapper`, also it sounds like border may be appropriate for having a bottom line at the bottom of `#wrapper` if I'm understanding you correctly.  check this http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/kWJ79/25/

Answer (score 0):

The `hr` doesn't appear short to me.  What browser are you using?

The reason there appears to be `padding` on the `#wrapper` is because you have content in it (`wrapper::after`) which is being rendered by the browser so it's height it included within the wrapper div.

Edit: seen the `hr`, for some reason I missed it when examining the code in Chrome.  As said previously, the containing div is only `1px`.

Answer (score 0):

`#vr` is set to `height: 100%`, so it takes the full height of it's parent, `#wrapper`.  Which contains only floated children and does not have a height specified.   You can specify the height of `#vr` as `height: 554px;` and it will line up.  Or you can specify a height on `#wrapper` but that will require other mods.

Comment: #wrapper doesn't have a height because it adapts to its children. As the contents are dynamic, I can't specify the height of #vr exactly. Are there any other options?

Comment: why don't you get rid of `#vr` and just add these rules to `#right`:

    `border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;`